How can I progress on the Sudoku portion of "The Grave of Schrödinger" by fjam from here?
Almost 1 year ago, I posted the puzzle "Sudoku variants #1: Schrödinger's Grave (6x6 grid)", which was based off of a Sudoku variant created by fjam. While the original puzzle sadly turned out to be impossible, I have been studying the ruleset since then and have a (solvable) remastered version that I plan to post relatively close to its 1 year anniversary.
However, I have been trying to solve the original puzzle by fjam without using any outside resources so I can be sure that I understand the ruleset and so that I know how to solve puzzles like this. (Although the "remastered" version of my old puzzle is indeed solvable and is legitimate according to the rules)
While I have been able to make some progress, I'm not sure what exactly I can figure out about the Sudoku to be able to make progress on it from here.

Rules

Normal Sudoku rules almost apply. Place the digits 0-9 into cells such that each digit appears once in every row, column and region. To accommodate this, one cell in each row, column and region is a Schrödinger cell, which contains two digits. In graves (cages), digits must sum to the day, month or year of the date on the grave. Escape the graveyard by carefully plotting an orthogonally connected path between the green and red cells. The path may not cross the highest or lowest digits in a grave.


My current progress on the puzzle (full progress)

First off, we can deduce that for the first box, either R1C3 or R3C1 is a Schrödinger cell, or else we wouldn't be able to draw a line from R1C1 to either of R1C2 or R2C1.


We also must have that the grave containing R2C2, R2C3, R3C2 and R3C3 does not add up to 30 or 31 (and therefore adds up to 8), because of the need for a Schrödinger cell in either R1C3 or R3C1.


Because of 1* (and because of "secret sharing" [nb 1]), we have that (1) R1C1=3, (2) R1C3 is the Schrödinger cell = 4/9 (which then implies that R1C2=7) and then (3) R2C1 and R3C1 is a 6-8 combo. This leaves us with a 0,1,2,5 to place in Box 1.

[nb 1]While I don't exactly remember entirely my thought process for this, I believe it had to do with how we still need that the total value of all 9 3x3 regions still need to add up to a total of 45, knowing that the 2x2 region in Box 1 must add up to 8.

The line now must be run through R1C1, R1C2, and then into R2C2.


We must have that we can't have both of that R2C2={1,2} and R3C2={1,2}. This is because if that was true, then the line must pass into R4C2. This then implies that R4C3 is a Schrödinger cell, which is impossible because R1C3 is a Schrödinger cell. Therefore, we have R2C2={1,2} and R2C3={1,2}, and also that R3C2={0,5} and R3C3={0,5}.
Since the line crosses over into R2C4, since that is a 2-cell grave, that means that R3C4 is Schrödinger and the line passes into R2C5. Now, the line can't pass through R2C7 because that implies that (since R2C7 and R3C7 form a 2-cell grave) R3C7 is Schrödinger, which contradicts the fact that R3C4 is.


So therefore, the line must therefore go down into R4C5 (implying that R5C5 is Schrödinger because of it being a 2-cell grave). Because we have a 2-cell grave right next to it containing R4C6 and R5C6, the line must go to the left to R4C3 (and therefore R4C2 is Schrödinger).

However, while I have made progress on figuring out where the line extends to and some of the locations of the Schrödinger cells, my question is: How can I make progress on the Sudoku portion of this puzzle from here?

Screenshot of current progress:

Dark gray: Location of Schrödinger cell, Orange: Location of maximum or minimum value in a cell

For point 1, why can't the two cages (top and left) be without a Schrödinger cell?

@FlorianF If R1C2 was Schrödinger, we would end up with a contradiction when drawing the line through R4C2, and I believe (drawing out the path in my head) that we are supposed to have a Schrödinger cell in R2C7, which is a contradiction if R2C1 is Schrödinger.


 As you are just looking for a next step, I would suggest looking at the top row. Here the numbers you already filled in add up to 23, leaving 22 for the remaining 6 cells. This gives you the sums of the two remaining graves in the top row and with a little bit of deduction the values for the other 2 graves in the top middle block as well. You should be able to proceed from there.

